# How to force the change the image of a view immediately after calling setImageResource?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to change the image of a ImageView immediately after I click it.

I tried using `.setImageDrawable` and calling `.invalidate()` on that view, without any success.

I'm probably not doing it right, but I'm trying to click the image, put the Thread to `sleep` for 2 seconds then display another image to the user.

The code is quite simple, and it's something like this:

```
myImage.setImageResource(R.id.myPicture);
... computations
... put the thread to sleep for 2 seconds
myImage.setImageResource(R.id.newPicture);
```

and the user can't see "myPicture" for those 2 seconds of sleep, and then it changes to "newPicture"

Comment: A little code would be helpful to help you better with your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sendMessageDelayed()` method of `handler` to perform any task at a delay of some specific amount of time. and write the logic to setImageDrawable inside that handler

**See the sample code**

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Message msg = new Message();
        photoGridHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, 2000);// delay of 2000 milisecond = 2 second

    }


    private Handler photoGridHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            photoGrid.setImageDrawable(myImage);

        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newimage);`. Place both the images in your `drawable` folder

Comment: Unfortunately it's the same story :(

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when mixing the UI thread and computations thread.  I would recommend trying an AsyncTask and pass it imageView.  Do your computations in the doInBackground of the asynctask and then in the onPostExecute change the image.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I have already used the solution I accepted in this post, and worked nicely, but I'll have a look at this and probably use it in other places in my applications. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: no problem, I saw the accepted answer after I posted.  Async is great if you want to do something right before the calculations as well, I use it to start loading animations before the calculations and then stop them in the onPostExecute.  Good luck on the app!!