# How to change the image of an ImageView immediately after clicking a button?

Tags: android, button, click, imageview

Probably I am not doing it right. I was trying to change an image right after a button is clicked. But whatever way I follow, it takes about at least 1/1.5 seconds to get the changed image. I thought that might be happening because of the image size. But after reducing the size, still the problem remains. I tried to do as it is said in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653053/how-to-force-the-change-the-image-of-a-view-immediately-after-calling-setimagere.)

But no luck. Still the image changes with a delay.

Can someone help me out with the right way?

Here is the code I used to change my image.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View arg0){

                        if(isOn){

                        portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.torch1);

                    }/
```

after clicking the button, I want immediate change of the resource image.

here is the xml block I used to display the image.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/inside_imageview"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/inside_imageview"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/inside_imageview"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/inside_imageview"  
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/on" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you looked at selectors?

Comment: Can you please elaborately brief me about selectors @hoomi?

Comment: Have a look at this while I try to find a tutorial (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: I think that the problem is in the isOn variable maybe it waits for a web request or something else, that's maybe your source of troubles, what dose isOn stands for ?

Comment: Here is a tutorial (http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/03/android-button-selector-tutorial-with.html#.VBQqLC5dXMU)

Comment: Nope, isOn is a very simple boolean variable which doesn't need anything to be completed before. @ Nadir B

Comment: Nope,I am not used any buttons selectors. Actually I am trying to change the entire image on a button click@ hoomi

Answer (score 0):

ok did you try simply this way ?

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            portrait.setImageResource(R.drawable.YOUR_NEWIMAGE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes I did. But it didn't work for me. Image gets changed but after a delay. What can I do about it? I need to change the image without delay.

Comment: I have added the code in my question @ Nadir B. Please have a look there.